# example of algebraic variety with infinitely many singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, cardinals, schemes, singularity, projective-varieties

Let $X$ ba an algebraic variety and $\mathrm{Sing}(X)$ be the set of all singular points.
For a set $A$ , $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of $A$ .

I konw examples of algebraic variety with finite singularities.
But I cannot get algebraic varieties which have infinitely many singularities.

I have following questions.

**My questions**
$(1)$ Can you construct algebraic varieties $X$ satisfying $|\mathrm{Sing}(X)|=|\mathbb{R}|$ $??$
$(2)$ Can you construct algebraic varieties $Y$ satisfying $|\mathrm{Sing}(Y)|=|\mathbb{Q}|$ $??$

Comment: Your question is not really precise since you should tell us over which field/ring do you consider the variety. Anyway the singular set is a closed set of the variety, so for example 2 can't happens if say you are looking at $\Bbb R$-points of a variety. (Assuming that variety means variety of finite type). 
Else, you can take $x = y = 0$ which has infinitely many singularities along the axis $(0,0,z)$.

Comment: You can take the product by $\otimes_K \operatorname{Spec}(K[x])$ and the singular points  will become lines the size of $K$. For example $\operatorname{Spec}(K[x,y,z]/(x^2-y^3))$.